# Android, NDK, building static library

Tags: android, android-ndk, static-libraries

Is it possible to build static (.a) library using ndk-build from several other static (.a) libraries.

For example, I have several libraries: lib1.a, lib2.a, lib3.a and I need to build libmegalib.a lib

Using LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES and include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY) dosn't help.
It creates libmegalib.a lib, but it contains "!<arch>" content only (8 bytes).

But I need libmegalib.a contain all my libs: lib1.a, lib2.a, lib3.a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use [ar](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ar.htm) (`arm-linux-androideabi-ar` from the appropriate NDK toolchain) to achieve this:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-ar -xv lib1.a 
arm-linux-androideabi-ar -xv lib2.a 
arm-linux-androideabi-ar -xv lib3.a 
arm-linux-androideabi-ar -rc libmegalib.a *.o
```